# Image Sequence Play Once Stop

Tags: javascript, image, sequence

I have a Javascript that loads images from the resource folder, then plays the image sequence back. However it loops the playback infinitely. I'd like the sequence to play once then stop on the last frame of the sequence. Here is the image sequence loader/repeater script.

```
private var quarterCircleValues = [];
var texture : Texture;
renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
var changeInterval = 0.33;

function Awake() {
quarterCircleValues = image_Loader.LoadSequence("adowner", 0150);
}

function Update() {
if( quarterCircleValues.length == 0) //nothing if no textures
return;

//we want this texture index now
var index :int = Time.time / changeInterval;

//take a module so that animation repeats 
index = index % quarterCircleValues.length;
//assign it
renderer.material.mainTexture = quarterCircleValues[index];  
}
```

I've tried removing the 'repeat module' but that results in the sequence playing once
per session then leaves a blank display. How can I program it to play once then stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'd go for

```
if (index < quarterCircleValues.length) {
    renderer.material.mainTexture = quarterCircleValues[index];  
}
```

instead of

```
//take a module so that animation repeats 
index = index % quarterCircleValues.length;
//assign it
renderer.material.mainTexture = quarterCircleValues[index];
```

or even try to stop the interval that must be calling the Update-function if the index is too large (that would be better). But I don't know what you're using, so I can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. I'm using Unity 3D.  I've tried replacing the original update with your code and removing the animation module. It didn't recognize the index!

Comment: hmm, that wasn't what I ment, rephrased it.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to be working out. I tried replacing the index modulo operative with your method and it resulted in a blank texture again.  Seems like there should be some modification of the modulo itself that would make it play once. A different symbol other than the % sign to multiply it by 1...I don't know! That's why I'm asking.